# How to use a dataclass toString with multiple arguments?

Tags: java, android

```
ArrayList<Items> itemsClass = new ArrayList<Items>();

itemClass.add(new Items(String, int, boolean));

public class Items{

    String x;
    int y;
    boolean z;

    public Items(String x, int y, boolean z){
        x = this.x;
        y = this.y;
        z = this.z;
    }

    public toString(){

        /*
         *This is my question
        */

    }

}
```

How do i write the toString method with a constructor in this class so i can add to my ArrayList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toString method will have nothing to do with adding to your ArrayList.
The toString method will be used to print out the object in a way that you desire.
If you write

```
// Instantiate the itemsClass
ArrayList itemsClass = new ArrayList();

// Add multiple Items to the itemClass
itemClass.add(new Items("String1", 0, true));
itemClass.add(new Items("String2", 1, true));

// Uses the individual itemClasses toString methods
System.out.println(itemClass[0]);
System.out.println(itemClass[1]);
```

You were missing your return type for the toString.
Something like this would work for your items toString:

```
public String toString(){
   string result = "";
   result += "String: " + x + "\n";
   result += "Integer: " + y + "\n";
   result += "Boolean: " + z + "\n";
   return result;
}
```

This would produce output like this:

```
String:  String1
Integer: true
Boolean: 1

String: String2
Integer: true
Boolean: 1
```